# Magento2 localisation Javascript

Tags: template, javascript, magento2, localisation, locale

A similar question was already asked here: [Magento 2 javascript text translations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38039/magento-2-javascript-text-translations), but Magento updated this translation technique in the beta version.

How can I add or update translations used by Javascript?

I figured out that Magento creates a file called 'js-translation.json' in the static folder. If I edit this file directly, I see that my translations are updated. But where is this file created, and how can I add translations so that Magento will automatically add this to js-translation.json when it's generated?

### Update

The correct answer to this question is still not given, altough Mage2.PRO pointed me to the right direction, it's not the full answer. My js-translation.json is still empty when generated.

For example, I like to translate the Add To Cart button. This button has three states, Add To Cart, Adding... and Added... How can I translate these words? Another example, the 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' text in the minicart. I think all these phrases should be translated from js-translation.json, but where to add them so these file is filled with these translations?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but I think the answer provided by mage2.pro is the correct one. If you have for example this in one of the js files `$.mage.__('Add To Cart')` it will be automatically picked up by the `setup:static-content:deploy` command. The only catch is that you have to have in the locale files a different translation for the text. The texts that have as translation the same text are not added to the json file in order to not increase the size without a reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if you figured it out already, but I thought I'd answer anyway..

I guess the other answers are heading in the right direction.

**Assuming you already have the translations installed, if not please:**

`bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d source_nl_NL.csv . nl_NL`

**So, first of all, please clear the cache(as others suggested as well):**

`rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed`

**Secondly, please clear your pub/static folder:**

`rm -rf pub/static/*/`

**Then we regenerate the static-content:** (I missed the langcode in the other answers..)

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL` - Make sure you add the langcode

**Now check if there were any js-translation.json created:**

`find pub/static/ -name "js-translation.json"`

Most likely you'll get a list of `js-translation.json` files. Please check these files and delete them if they're empty or contain something like `[]`.

Comment: Thanks Timon, this is indeed the way to go! I figured this out myself a while ago, but did not post the answer here yet. This is a great addition to the question.

Comment: @Silvan In my installation the file js-translation.json has already some phrases translated in my locale but there are still phrases not being translated, should I added them manually to this file?

Comment: I would not recommend this, because the js-translation file wil be overwritten the next time you deploy static files. In that case you should add the phrases manually every time that you did a deploy. Are these phrases present in the language pack?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add translations to .csv files,
then be sure that next steps are executed:

1. Cache Storage should be flushed (basically var/cache and var/view_preprocessed folders should be cleared)
2. Static files should be redeployed (delete all folders inside pub/static and run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all cache and delele pub/static folder content.

Go to your root directory and run below command:-

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Hopefully your problem will be resolved.

Comment: ArkadiyCh also told me to remove cache and redeploy static files, unfortunately this does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like "Cannot translate phrases in $.mage.__('XXX')" when phrase in phtml worked perfect. 
So, the solution was ingeniously simple.

$t(...)  and $.mage analizes only files *.js

Consequently it does not fall into the js-translation dictionary.

So when rendering a section script in phtml files, you should directly insert the already translated phrases with wrappers `__('Translated phrase')` .