# How to translate JS error message or text in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, js-translation

I have two views English and Arabic default js validation error message needs to translate in Arabic so how to do it? And also I have a few custom texts on how to do it.

I created an i18n for Arabic is working fine if I do echo in PHTML or PHP file, the same way how to brig it into js also in Magento 2

anyone help me out

Answer (score 35):

You can translate js error message like this

```
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert($.mage.__('Enter Your message here'));
    });
});
```

Magento2 use `mage/translate.js` for translation

Comment: created ar_KW.csv in my module i18n folder in that  translated "Enter Your message here" in my j i tried it not working but in phtml if i do echo my translated text i displaying

Comment: Did you clear your cache and static-content deploy ? @PradeepKumar

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for! +1

Comment: Be aware that this will not work if you use it directly in phtml files. Magento will only parse and translate from js and html files.

Comment: This will work but is not the that clean of a code; you are requiring mage/translate but are not using it. .

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
define(
    [
        'mage/translate'
    ],
    function (
        $tr
    ) {

        $tr('<your text>'),
    }
);
```

Comment: Reference: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment.js

Comment: All right but the variable name for the `mage/translate` must be `$t`, not the `$tr` https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293771/the-i18ncollect-phrases-command-does-not-collect-all-translatable-strings-fro/293772#293772

Answer (score 11):

Additional note: if you need to include some variable to translation (in js), you can [use this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html):

```
$.mage.__('Hello %1').replace('%1', yourVariable);
```

Answer (score 5):

after digging deep i come to know the concept of localization in magento2

below are thing you need to follow , in my website we have two view  en and ar_kw Arabic

1. Create language package http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2
2. to get all phrases you need to run command   ex

   ```
   php D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Sugarcode\Test\i18n\ar_KW.csv" D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Sugarcode\Test
   ```

   it ill read my test module and create a csv Sugarcode\Test\i18n\ar_KW.csv

it will get all `__('Some Text') and $.mage.__('Some Text')` in js and prepare a csv

3. now translate the newly generated file to Arabic which you can keep in name of ar_KW.csv locale code (it may be inside your module or it may be inside you language module )
4. remove var folder  and run `bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ar_KW`
5. it will create all js along with js-translation.json file  in each theme/ ex luma/ar_KW,  js-translation.json will have all js side translated data in json format when ever you see the error msg it ill shown from this file only

Comment: Hello, i have done all steps as per your answer, the code i added for ex : alert($.mage.__('js test')); is correctly coming in the language file generating but when i change the translatiion the js message still comes the same. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

it throw error if you use __ so follow below code

```
  require([
    'jquery', // jquery Library
    'mage/translate'
   ], function($,$t){ 
        $(window).load(function() {
            alert($t('Enter Your message here'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with js translations so i created a new language pack within `app/i18n/...` folder and refresh the cache.

See [translating problem in JS templates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98209/34044).

Answer (score -1):

Add in a template .phtml your error message like :
 `<?php  echo __('This is a required field.'); ?>`
 - active translate online
 - translate

done

Comment: Could you add some more details for the answer as to _how_ and _why_ it works?