# Magento 2 Cannot translate phases in $.mage.__('XXX')

Tags: magento2, localisation

Translation added to i18n files, phrases in `<?php echo __("XXX");?>`can be translated, but the those in `$.mage.__('XXX')` cannot be translated.

Any work around to translate phrases in `$.mage.__('XXX')`?

Comment: You can check with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99966/how-to-translate-js-error-message-or-text-in-magento-2

Comment: have you keep mage/translate in your js?

Comment: @fschmengler No duplication found in js-translation.json

Comment: I had the same problem like "Cannot translate phases in $.mage.__('XXX')" when phrase in phtml worked perfect. 
So, the solution was ingeniously simple.

$t(...)  and $.mage analizes only files *.js

Consequently it does not fall into the js-translation dictionary.

So when rendering a section script in phtml files, you should directly insert the already translated phrases with wrappers `__('Translated phrase')` .

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer the question myself:

Adding the code below to phtml file:

```
<?php
$_data = array(
    'Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?' => __('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?'),
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery", "mage/translate"], 
    function ($) {
        $.mage.translate.add(<?php echo Zend_Json::encode($_data) ?>)
    });
</script>
```