# Magento2-Translation not working in js files

Tags: magento2, language, translate, js-translation

I was trying to make translation in JS files.

I have tried

- 1

> ```
> require([
> 'jquery',
> 'jquery/ui', 
> 'mage/translate'
> ], function($){ 
>     $(window).load(function() {
>         alert($.mage.__('Your Message'));
>     });
> });
> ```

- 2

> ```
> <?php echo __('Create Backup') ?>
> ```

But nothing worked. It's working fine for strings added in php code.

Comment: check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99966/how-to-translate-js-error-message-or-text-in-magento-2) link maybe any one answer solve your issue

Comment: Hi @Hit's I have gone through the link and tried.Nothing helps.

Comment: But as per my link, it should work, maybe you doing something wrong, did you got any errors in console/var/log folder?

Comment: I haven't got any errors @Hit's

Comment: This should solve your problem, please try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260843/42841

Comment: Thanks for the link @Pinky_P , I'll look,try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I understood that flushing the translation cache was not deleting the `js-translation.json` in pub/static/path/to/appropriate/theme/locale. After deleting, the file was renewed and things where going on.

It is actually what is suggested in the comment @Pinky_P made but was hidden to me :(.

Comment: thank you for that! it's a fix!