# The "i18n:collect-phrases" command does not collect all translatable strings from JS

Tags: magento2.3, i18n, js-translation

During module development I trying to collect all translations to the `i18n/en_US.csv` file using regular command:

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US.csv /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module
```

But it collected not all phrases. Phrases from JS was missed, which written like that one:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Vendor_Module/js/action/generate-method',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, Component, ko, methodsGenerator, registry, $tr) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            visible: false,
            changeLocationLabel: $tr('Change my location')
        },
```

As a result the ***'Change my location'*** phrase was missed in the `i18n/en_US.csv` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 use the `\Magento\Setup\Module\I18n\Parser\Adapter\Js::_parse()` method to collect all translatable lines (strings) from a files. It will open all `js` files one-by-one and read each line of code searching for a strings that match a pattern of regular expression:

```
'/mage\.__\(\s*([\'"])(.*?[^\\\])\1.*?[),]/'
```

or

```
'/\\$t\(\s*([\'"])(.*?[^\\\])\1.*?[),]/'
```

So, if you wish your string was added to the translation using phrase collector you should write it this way (using `$t` as a variable name, not the `$tr`):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Vendor_Module/js/action/generate-method',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, Component, ko, methodsGenerator, registry, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            visible: false,
            changeLocationLabel: $t('Change my location')
        },
```

because the Magento accepts only the `$t` as a variable name for the `mage/translate` object. Another variables will be not parsed and strings from that functions will be not added to the `.csv` result file.

Another way is adding the `mage/translate` as a dependency in your class and use it calling `$.mage.__('Change my location')` which will be correctly parsed during phrase collecting too.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html#add_strings_js

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks you very much !