# How to properly translate strings in JavaScript

Tags: magento2, localisation, inline-translations, js-translation

Say I have a piece of custom JavaScript loaded in some pages of my store. This JavaScript serves the purpose of interactivity and can display some text. How would I make it multi-langual like I would with the `__("string");` format in PHP?

Say i.e. I have this piece of JavaScript:

```
$('.readmorebutton').click(function() {
    if (! $('.readmore').hasClass('open') ) {
        $('.readmorebutton').text('Show less'); //How to translate?
    } else {
        $('.readmorebutton').text('Read More'); //How to translate?
    }
});
```

note: JS is taken out of context and stripped down; the working of it is not the issue, the translating of the `text` is.

Comment: Have you place javascript code in phtml or js file?

Comment: This is in a custom.js loaded via XML, as it runs on all pages.

Comment: hence the title of my question ;)

Comment: Ok have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751094/magento-translate-text-from-javascript-files) ?

Comment: Hm no. That's based on Magento1 and Prototype (which I believe is no longer part of Mag2) but it did lead me to this answer, but it seems outdated nowadays too http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38039/magento-2-javascript-text-translations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your strings to be translated like so:

`$.mage.__('Foobar')`

```
$('.readmorebutton').click(function() {
    if (! $('.readmore').hasClass('open') ) {
        $('.readmorebutton').text($.mage.__('Show less')); //How to translate?
    } else {
        $('.readmorebutton').text($.mage.__('Read More')); //How to translate?
    }
});
```

Magento then should use the same translation files as your PHP/HTML code.

Don't forget to clear caches and re-deploy static content afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I made a easy solution:

```
let sometext = '<?php echo $this->__('text to be translated.'); ?>';

$('.readmorebutton').click(function() {
    if (! $('.readmore').hasClass('open') ) {
        $('.readmorebutton').text(sometext);
    } else {
        $('.readmorebutton').text('Read More');
    }
});
```